# How to increment and keep previous increments when values are the same in emacs

Tags: emacs

I have two columns with values, the second column starts at particular value, I want the second column to start with one, and increment only whenever a value changes, otherwise keep the previous increment. I can use macro to set the start count, but how to make sure that same values remains the same as shown ?,

Problem:

```
0,39
1,39
2,39
3,39
4,40
5,40
6,40
7,41
```

I want this:

```
0, 1
1, 1
2, 1
3, 1
4, 2
5, 2
6, 2
7, 3
```

Comment: Do you really want to do this in emacs? It would be about 4 lines of Python.

Comment: ...If you have the solution in python, you can help me, Though I have very big file with those number patterns, and in emacs is where I live :P

Answer (score 2):

I'm curious to see other answers so I can learn something.

Meanwhile it seems to me there are two main approaches:

## Parsing to a list of lists, transforming, and re-inserting

An obvious, elegant approach would be to parse the CSV file into a list of lists (a list of rows, each of which is a list of columns), do the transformation, `delete-region` the whole buffer, and insert back the results.

Probably you could use the `parse-csv` and `dashes` packages from MELPA -- the former for CSV style parsing and the latter for a `partition` function.  Or you could write bespoke code to do this.

## Line by line

For larger files, the above approach is likely to be slow. That list of lists is going to be large and require lots of garbage collection.

Think of Emacs as a buffer-manipulation library that happens to have a text editor around it. Often it's faster to party directly on the buffer, especially for this type of linear row-by-row transformation. In that spirit:

```el
(defun my/stack-overflow-33646950 ()
  "Transform the current buffer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33646950/how-to-increment-and-keep-previous-increments-when-values-are-the-same-in-emacs"
  (interactive)
  (let ((prev-y nil)
        (band   0))
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (not (eobp))
      (let* ((bol  (save-excursion (beginning-of-line) (point)))
             (eol  (save-excursion (end-of-line) (point)))
             (line (buffer-substring-no-properties bol eol)))
        (pcase (mapcar #'string-to-number
                       (split-string line "," t "[ \t]+"))
          (`(,x ,y)
           (unless (eq y prev-y)
             (setq prev-y y)
             (setq band (1+ band)))
           (delete-region bol eol)
           (insert (format "%s,%s" x band))
           (goto-char (1+ eol)))
          (_ (user-error "expected <number>,<number> but found \"%s\"" line)))))))
```

Comment: ...man the second approach is fast, it took few seconds for 19140 lines file. thanks for emacs approach!

Comment: Glad to hear that. It could probably be even faster. With fresh eyes this morning, don't need to do so much nav to beg and end of line; that could be simplified. Also, could inhibit motion hooks from running. Maybe even disable undo?

Comment: ...My mind was fixed in macros way!, but writing a an elisp function was the way to go. P

Answer (score 1):

Regexp replace:

- Start regexp replace `C-M-%`
- Search string `\([0-9]+\)$`, which matches the last number and captures it.
- Replace string `\,(format " %d" (- \#1 38))`, which converts the captured group into an integer (`\#1`), subtracts 38, and formats as a decimal.  The `\,` is the magic thing that builds your replace string from lisp code.
- `<space>` to replace one at a time, or `!` to replace all.  You can narrow the buffer or set the region to only work on a subset of the buffer.

There are many other ways to solve this, but they require extra configuration and/or installing packages (take a look at keyboard macros and evil-numbers, for example).

If the file is big (like 1000 lines or bigger), use Python or some other scripting language.

Answer (score 0):

Python solution #1: if your data fit in to RAM and you like numpy:

```
import numpy
data = numpy.loadtxt('data.txt', delimiter=',')
data[:,1] -= data[0,1]-1                                
numpy.savetxt('output.txt', data, delimiter=', ', fmt='%d')
```

Python solution #2: if you prefer line-by-line text manipulation:

```
first = None
for line in open('data.txt'):
    v0, v1 = line.split(',')
    if first is None:
        first = int(v1)
    print '%s, %d' % (v0, int(v1)-first+1)
```